# pruned(text): expected argument #0(zero-based) to be a Tensor; got list (['Roasted ants are a popular snack in Columbia'])

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the code to get embeddings using EMLo .

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

import tensorflow as tf

elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2")

x = ["Roasted ants are a popular snack in Columbia"]


embeddings = elmo(x, signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"] # To Extract ELMo features 

embeddings.shape
```

I'm getting this type error , `type error : pruned(text): expected argument #0(zero-based) to be a Tensor; got list (['Roasted ants are a popular snack in Columbia'])`.

Comment: I tried the code on my PC and it worked correctly. Cn you please provide more info about the error and where it is generated?

Comment: @madhurika: were you able to solve this issue? If yes, can you share the resolution step please?

Comment: check the tensorflow version, are you using >2.0?

Comment: @madhurika: I am receiving this same error. Any chance you could post the solution if you found it?

Answer (score 0):

This code runs fine with `Tensorflow 2.7` in colab,

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

import tensorflow as tf

elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2")

x = ["Roasted ants are a popular snack in Columbia"]


embeddings = elmo(x, signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"] # To Extract ELMo features 

embeddings.shape
```

Output:

```
TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(8), Dimension(1024)])
```

Let us know which `tensorflow` version and `environment` are using to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
elmo = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3")

x = tf.constant(["Roasted ants are a popular snack in Columbia"])


embeddings = elmo.signatures["default"](x)["elmo"] # To Extract ELMo features 

embeddings.shape
```

thoe output will be:

```
TensorShape([1, 8, 1024])
```

also you can use this code:

```
elmo = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3",signature= "default",signature_outputs_as_dict= True)
embeddings = elmo(
    tf.constant(["Roasted ants are a popular snack in Columbia"]))

# Different outputs can be accessed by name, eg:
print( embeddings["elmo"].shape)
```